# Http post response issue in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to get download the server response content as csv. While doing the same I have getting 2 errors.

Method given below:

```
generateCsv(exportModel: any) {
    let headers={};
    return this.http.post<any>(ReportConstant.exportApi, exportModel,
        { observe:"response",responseType: 'blob'})
}
```

The error:

> ERROR in src/app/components/export/_services/export.service.ts(22,91): error TS2322: Type '"response"' is not assignable to type
>       '"body"'.
>
> src/app/components/export/_services/export.service.ts(22,110): error TS2322: Type '"blob"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.

I am very new with front end technologies. Kindly suggest me the solution to resolve the issue.

Comment: Why are you using a **POST** call to fetch data? It should be a **GET**. And what is the type of `exportModel`?

Comment: Can you try changing ```responseType: 'blob'``` to ```responseType: 'blob' as 'json'```?

Comment: let headers = data.headers; 
    let contentDisposition= headers.get('content-disposition'); 
    let filename = contentDisposition.split(';')[1].split('filename')[1].split('=')[1].trim();

Comment: this is the area where I got the error when try to add responsetype : 'blob' as 'json'.

Comment: @Arcteezy : can you provide the syntax for an angular 8 GET method.

Comment: Remove the `<any>`. If you pass such a generic type when calling the mehod, yu're choosing the overload that passes "json" as the response type.

Comment: @SüreshAK `this.http.get()` But you can't pass payload in GET request. So if your `exportModel` parameter is an object, you have to pass its details as query params.

Comment: @Arcteezy exportModel is an object and it contains lots of parameters

Comment: These are the possible options : 1) Pass all parameters individually, 2) Pass the object as whole in params after stringify (Wouldn't recommend) or 3) Make a POST call to prepare data and make another GET call to fetch prepared data.

Answer (score 0):

```
     return  this.httpClient.post(url,
            body,
            {
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }),
                observe: 'response',
                responseType: 'blob'
            }
        );
```

Answer (score -1):

The way you are using the POST API(Http Client) is wrong

If you are passing more data to server use **POST** or else **GET** should do the Job

**POST:**
import statemenet in case you are doubtful

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpParameterCodec} from "@angular/common/http";
```

add this in your constructor

```
private httpClient: HttpClient
```

Code starts:

```
let body = new HttpParams({encoder: new CustomEncoder()});
body = body.append('args', 'stringArguments')); //Add needed arguments

//Set header and response types

let options= {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'),
      responseType:'text' as 'json'
    };

// This will return a promise(observable) which can be called utilized as 
// observableReturn.subscribe(response => this.ProcessAsyncResponse(response), error => this.HandleSRProcessError(error, this.serviceRequestCallList));

return this.httpClient.post(ajaxUrl, body, options)
```